# jQuery Mobile double scrollbar CSS

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, scrollbar

I'm experiencing a problem with jQuery Mobile. When there is not enough content on the page a vertical scroll bar will appear, so there'll be two scrollbars on the page. I'm using left and right panels with data-display="push" (if this is relevant).

Perhaps the problem lies with how I include my CSS files? In my "main" CSS file I override some of the jQuery Mobile CSS styles. Is this the correct way to customize the jQuery Mobile CSS - besides using the Themeroller, which I haven't yet used? I'm mostly changing things like padding, margin etc.

One thing I noticed is that if I change the ui-content class from overflow-x:hidden, to overflow-x:visible, then the scrollbar will disappear.

So my questions are:

1. Why is the scrollbar appearing?
2. Am I including the jQuery Mobile CSS file in the correct order? Before my own CSS file?
3. If I use the Themeroller, must I use the generated CSS file as well as a structure CSS file? The structure file appearing after the Themeroller file?

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry if I ramble. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Your custom CSS is conflicting with jQM's CSS 2) Add your own CSS before jQM. 3) structure CSS should be included before ThemeRoller custom CSS.

Comment: Thank you for replying Omar. I had a look at the ThemeRoller website where they say that the custom theme needs to be added before the structure CSS file. Not sure what to do now. With regards to my main.css file, if I include it before jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css, won't the latter rules override the former? Thanks

Comment: You need to try all possible ways in order to find perfect solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with two things, the css that you are linking and the order that you are linking them.

When you use a theme, you do not want to link the regular **jquery.mobile.css** file at all, but rather need to first link your **theme css** file, then the *structure* file **jquery.mobile.*structure*.min.css** only.  You should probably also include the **mobile.icons** file too.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/your-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure.min.css">
```